# Hierarchies Level extract data till the end of Levels

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

How to parse tree format Hierarchies Level in

ResponseData from API call currently It hold two Level Hierarchies

```
{
  "result" : [
    {
      "name": "HIERARCHIES LEVELS",
      "hierarchies" : [
        {
          "hierarchy_order" : 1,
          "hierarchy_level" : 1,
           "name": "LEVEL ONE",
          "hierarchies" : [
            {

              "hierarchy_order" : 1,
              "hierarchy_level" : 2,
               "name": "LEVEL TWO",
              "hierarchies" : [

              ],
              "is_enabled" : true
            }
          ],
          "is_enabled" : true
        },
        {
          "hierarchy_order" : 1,
          "hierarchy_level" : 1,
           "name": "LEVEL ONE",
          "hierarchies" : [
            {

              "hierarchy_order" : 1,
              "name" : "LEVEL TWO",
              "hierarchy_level" : 2,
              "hierarchies" : [

              ],
              "is_enabled" : true
            },
            {

              "hierarchy_order" : 1,
              "name" : "LEVEL TWO",
              "hierarchy_level" : 2,
              "hierarchies" : [

              ],
              "is_enabled" : true
            }
          ],
          "is_enabled" : true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

ModelClass

```
struct AssignedHierarchyLevelModel {

    let result: [Result]?

    init(_ json: JSON) {
        result = json["result"].arrayValue.map { Result($0) }
    }

    struct Result {

        let name: String?
        let hierarchies: [Hierarchies]?

        init(_ json: JSON) {
            name = json["name"].stringValue
            hierarchies = json["hierarchies"].arrayValue.map { Hierarchies($0) }
        }

    }

    struct Hierarchies {

        let hierarchyOrder: Int?
        let hierarchyLevel: Int?
        let name: String?
        let hierarchies: [Hierarchies]?
        let isEnabled: Bool?

        init(_ json: JSON) {
            hierarchyOrder = json["hierarchy_order"].intValue
            hierarchyLevel = json["hierarchy_level"].intValue
            name = json["name"].stringValue
            hierarchies = json["hierarchies"].arrayValue.map { Hierarchies($0) }
            isEnabled = json["is_enabled"].boolValue
        }

    }

    struct Hierarchies {

        let hierarchyOrder: Int?
        let hierarchyLevel: Int?
        let name: String?
        let hierarchies: [Hierarchies]?
        let isEnabled: Bool?

        init(_ json: JSON) {
            hierarchyOrder = json["hierarchy_order"].intValue
            hierarchyLevel = json["hierarchy_level"].intValue
            name = json["name"].stringValue
            hierarchies = json["hierarchies"].arrayValue.map { Hierarchies($0) }
            isEnabled = json["is_enabled"].boolValue
        }

    }

}
```

After Response

```
   var assignedhierarchyResult = [AssignedHierarchyLevelModel.Result]()

        func dataBindAccountSettingHierarchyLevel(){
            hierarchyParentList.removeAll()
            self.assignedhierarchyResult = self.assignedHierarchyLevelModel?.result ?? []
        }
```

// TableView Datasource Delegate Methods

```
func numberOfChild(assignedhierarchyChilds: [AssignedHierarchyLevelModel.Result]) -> Int {
    var arrayCount = [AssignedHierarchyLevelModel.Result.Hierarchies]()
    assignedhierarchyChilds.enumerated().forEach { (indexValue,element) in
        arrayCount.append(contentsOf: assignedhierarchyChilds[indexValue].hierarchies ?? [])
        if arrayCount[indexValue].hierarchies?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            arrayCount[indexValue].hierarchies?.enumerated().forEach({ (subIndex, subElement) in
                arrayCount.append(contentsOf: arrayCount[indexValue].hierarchies?[subIndex].hierarchies ?? [])
            })
        }
    }

    return arrayCount.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.numberOfChild(assignedhierarchyChilds: assignedhierarchyResult)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return assignedhierarchyResult.count
}
```

Trying to Hierarchy Level for tableview like **AccordionLevels**  unable to wrappe my data set from response date.  In normal tableview i display its shown Root-Parent and Child in tableview list.  Unable to get sublist of child.

How to get extract data from subChild of [Hierarchies] till the end of subElement of [Hierarchies]?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. A section is a top level hierarchy, fine. A section are what? Its children hierarchies and grand children one?

Comment: @Larme Iterating parent - > children -> grand children -> grand grand childer -> till the family level ends, That I want to do here.

Comment: But you want to display  them as the same level of "child"?

Comment: @Larme display will goes accordion levels

Comment: At least i need to get dataset in console to print so then I will bind the date to accordion tableview.

Answer (score 0):

to easily create Models(class/structs) for your json use Link :- https://app.quicktype.io/

And use json decoder to decode

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(struc.self, from: jsonData)
```

-> Your Model

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    var result: [Result]?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var hierarchies: [Hierarchy]?
}

// MARK: - Hierarchy
struct Hierarchy: Codable {
    var hierarchyOrder, hierarchyLevel: Int?
    var name: String?
    var hierarchies: [Hierarchy]?
    var isEnabled: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case hierarchyOrder = "hierarchy_order"
        case hierarchyLevel = "hierarchy_level"
        case name, hierarchies
        case isEnabled = "is_enabled"
    }
}
```

-> now you can easily use it like

```
let myStrut = Welcome()
myStruct.result[Index].hierarchies[Index].name
```

Comment: The issue is iterating till end of [hierarchies]  array in enumeration,  I Can able to display element names but unable to reach out the end of looping

Comment: Side note: `CodingKeys` could be ommited by using the setting on the `decoder` the snakeCase to camel.

Comment: can you share your data.. i can set it up in a table view for you

Comment: @Larme then you should be having every key in snake case